# Was the temple in the movie 'Ran' actually set on fire?

Tags: film-techniques, ran

In the movie *[Ran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ran_(film))*, there is a scene where a castle is getting invaded and part of it is set on fire. Knowing that the movie is from 1985 I doubt it was a special effect. Different camera angles tell me it all looks really real.

So I wondered how they managed to do this. Did they really burn a temple for the movie ?

[image: Image of a scene from the film where a temple is burned down]

Comment: Star Was was from that era and it had special effects

Comment: Not to mention that there was a real train crashed in *The General*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Imdb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089881/trivia?item=tr0687315)

> The castle destroyed in the middle of the movie was specially constructed on the slopes of Mount Fuji for the film and then burned down. No miniatures were used for that segment, although an optical of another castle being burned at the end was used.

So yes, it was real.

Comment: Yes, but it wasn't a real building used for other purposes for a period of time until the movie makers bought it, it was an outdoor set constructed for the movie, and might not have had a finished interior.  Thus it was not a temple or a castle but a movie set.